# How to create roll-ups in Informix SQL?

Tags: sql, informix

I often meet in different reports intermediate roll-ups like this:

```
|calltypename     |rating                                  |number |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-------+
|sales            |1.0                                     |1      |
|sales            |5.0                                     |2      |
|                 |3.666666666666666666666666666667        |3      |
|service          |1.0                                     |1      |
|service          |3.0                                     |1      |
|service          |5.0                                     |3      |
|service          |9.0                                     |1      |
|                 |4.666666666666666666666666666667        |6      |
```

Here records are grouped by calltypename with intermediate roll-ups: 
average rating and sum of numbers. 
Informix SQL have no ROLLUP operator, so I'm trying to achieve similar result with UNION:

```
select  calltypename, TO_NUMBER(datavalue) as rating, count(*) as number
from calldata
where datakey="qrate1" 
group by calltypename, rating
union all
select calltypename, AVG(TO_NUMBER(datavalue)) as rating, count(*) as number
from calldata
where datakey="qrate1" 
group by calltypename
order by calltypename, rating
```

It produces the following result:

```
|calltypename     |rating                                  |number |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------+-------+
|sales            |1.0                                     |1      |
|sales            |3.666666666666666666666666666667        |3      |
|sales            |5.0                                     |2      |
|service          |1.0                                     |1      |
|service          |3.0                                     |1      |
|service          |4.666666666666666666666666666667        |6      |
|service          |5.0                                     |3      |
|service          |9.0                                     |1      |
```

Is there any hint how to order the records so that roll-ups will always take their place below the related group?

After some time, I have found a solution that I do not like very much. Idea is to add a fake column "ROLLUP" that will be used in ORDER BY statement:

```
select calltypename as queue, "" as rollup,
datavalue as rating, count(*) as number
from calldata
where datakey="qrate1" 
group by queue, rating
union all
select calltypename as queue, "rollup" as rollup,
TO_CHAR(AVG(TO_NUMBER(datavalue)),"*.*") as rating, count(*) as number
from calldata
where datakey="qrate1"
group by queue
order by queue, rollup, rating
```

This produce a result:

```
 |queue  |rollup    |rating|number |
 +-------+----------+------+-------+
 |sales  |          |1     |1      |
 |sales  |          |5     |2      |
 |sales  |rollup    |3.7   |3      |
 |service|          |1     |1      |
 |service|          |3     |1      |
 |service|          |5     |3      |
 |service|          |9     |1      |
 |service|rollup    |4.7   |6      |
```

But I would like it without ROLLUP column...

Comment: The Informix SQL product (quite distinct from the Informix server, which implements SQL) has a report writing tool called ACE (`saceprep` is the compiler; `sacego` is the runner), and it handles rollups very easily (and result formatting and pagination — though it has a 'fixed-width font' mindset). However, that's probably not available on your machines — it used to be standard for most people once upon 20+ years ago, but that's in the distant past now. (If you go back far enough, there wasn't a separate Informix server; you bought Informix SQL or Informix 4GL and the server came too.)

Comment: How would you know which rows are the rollup rows if you don't have an explicit marker?  Remember, result sets are (unordered) sets unless you impose an ordering on the results.  And without the rollup marker, there's no way to know which rows are rollup rows and which are regular data rows.

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm working with IBM Informix Dynamic Server V12. As you wrote, it have no ACE. Strange that such a useful tool have completely gone; I would expect that it was replaced by something more modern and functional.

Comment: @Jonathan, you are right concerning explicit marker. I tried to follow an example [link](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-grouping-sets/), but still can't adapt it for my case

Comment: Maybe you could "brute force" the output you want by using your query with the `rollup` column and make it a table expression for another select, adding a conditional to change the value of column `queue` to `NULL` when it is the rollup value. Something like: `SELECT CASE WHEN a.rollup IS NOT NULL THEN NULL ELSE a.queue END AS queue, a.rating. a.number FROM ( *your query here* ) AS a;` .